# Why is Map<String, int> list = new HashMap<String, int> not permissible?

Tags: java, generics, hashmap

So as you can see be title I am confused on:

```
Map<String, int> list = new HashMap<String, int>
```

I am a bit lost in class on this specific topic and would appreciate if anybody could explain why and how it actually works.

Comment: What is the exact compiler message?

Comment: Why would you call a map `list`? :(

Comment: @DaveNewton  Premature Obfuscation?  ;)

Comment: @AndrewThompson yes premature obfuscation

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The type `int` is not a class, it's a primitive type.  Generic type parameters must be assigned classes, not primitive types.  You can use

```
Map<String, Integer> list = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
```

instead.  All Java primitive types have class wrappers, and as of Java 1.5, autoboxing allows expressions such as `map.put("dummy", 1);`, where `1` is autoboxed as an `Integer`.

Incidentally, it can be confusing to call a `Map` `list`.  You could remove the confusion by calling it `map`.

Comment: Thank you, I get where I was confused now

Comment: +1 With a nitpick: I would say "reference types" to cover arrays as well as classes.

Comment: It should be "reference type". It not only can be array or class or interface type, it can also be a parameterized type or a type parameter.

Answer (score 1):

IN java Some thing like following happens

```
public interface Map<K, V> {
    public K getKey();            
    public V getValue();          
}

public class HashMap<K, V> implements Map<K, V> {

    private K key;              //1
    private V value;            //2

    public K getKey()   { return key; }
    public V getValue() { return value; }
 //other getter setter methods 

}
```

As In
Here in place of<K,V> in

<String,int>  `int` is a primitive type And we `can't make object of primitive type`.
see //1 and //2 above in code

But <String,Integer> is possible as they are wrapper type and Objects can be made of them

Comment: so  satisfied with answer :)